# 'WebRequest.Create(string)' is obsolete:. Use HttpClient instead.'

Tags: c#, migration, httpclient, .net-6.0, webclient

hi i am migrating code from .net core to .net 6.0 and getting above mesprivate static HttpWebRequest

```
CreateSoapRequest(string url, string action)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", string.Format("\"{0}\"", action));
            return httpWebRequest;
        }
```

i did below to resolve this

```
CreateSoapRequest(string url, string action)
        {
 var client = new HttpClient();
            var httpResponse = client.PostAsync(url, httpWebRequest);
            var httpWebRequest = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", string.Format("\"{0}\"", action));
            httpWebRequest.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"");
            return httpResponse;
}
```

but the main issue is after doing this change i am getting errors on methods which is using this request

```
private static void AddMessageToRequest(string soapMessage, WebRequest request)
        {
            var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            
            LoadXml(soapMessage).Save(requestStream);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

private static string GetResponse(WebRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                return Read(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Response != null)
                {
                    return Read(ex.Response.GetResponseStream());
                }
                throw;
            }
        }




private static string PostSoap(string url, string soapMessage, string action)
        {
            var soapRequest = CreateSoapRequest(url, action);

            AddMessageToRequest(soapMessage, soapRequest);
            return GetResponse(soapRequest);
        }
```

can anybody help me to use httpclient in this case

Comment: What errors do you get? Why are you using `httpWebRequest` - `var httpResponse = client.PostAsync(url, httpWebRequest);` before declaring it?

Comment: @GuruStron if i use response as response of CreateSoapRequest to AddMessageToRequest method its telling  me to use httpclient and same for GetResponsemethod

Comment: TBH your comment has not made the issue you are facing any clearer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a large number of problems with your usage of `HttpClient`.

- You need to use `HttpRequestMessage` and that takes a `Content` which *already* has a stream inside it. You don't *ask* it for a stream, you *give* it one. So you need `StreamContent`.
- `PostAsync` is just a short version of the above, but you cannot set headers.
- You need `using` on the request and response.
- Cache the `HttpClient` to avoid socket exhaustion.
- Use `async` `await`.

```cs
static HttpClient _client = new();

HttpRequestMessage CreateSoapRequest(string url, string action)
{
    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    message.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"{action}\"");
    message.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"");
    return message;
}

private static void AddMessageToRequest(string soapMessage, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var mem = new MemoryStream();
    LoadXml(soapMessage).Save(requestStream);
    mem.Position = 0;
    message.Content = new StreamContent(mem, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
}

private static async Task<string> GetResponse(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    using var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    // maybe call response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode ??
    var str = await response.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return str;
}

private static string PostSoap(string url, string soapMessage, string action)
{
    using var soapRequest = CreateSoapRequest(url, action);
    AddMessageToRequest(soapMessage, soapRequest);
    return GetResponse(soapRequest);
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to use [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0) when creating your HttpClient

Comment: `CreateSoapRequest` method should return `message` variable.

Comment: Only In ASP.NET. Thanks fixed.